# Asp.Net AutoComplate List

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have problem autocomplate extender I wanna use autocompate in mmaster page.

ASPX Code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 top-search-holder no-margin">
                            <div class="search-area">
                                <div class="control-group" style="background-color: white">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtArama" CssClass="search-field" placeholder="Aranacak Kelimeyi girin..."></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TxtArama_AutoCompleteExtender" 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        DelimiterCharacters="" 
                                        Enabled="True" 
                                        ServiceMethod="GetProducts" 
                                        ServicePath="AutoComplate.asmx" 
                                        TargetControlID="TxtArama">
                                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

                                    <a class="search-button" href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="Aramaci_OnServerClick"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

AutoComplate.asmx

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
//[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class AutoComplate : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod()]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public string[] GetProducts(string prefixText,int count)
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        ArrayList PN = new ArrayList();
        DT = DbClass.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%'", "MySql");
        if (DT.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                PN.Add(DT.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString());
            }

        }
        return (string[]) (PN.ToArray(typeof (string)));
    }
}
```

I type word call method get data but not see list bellow in textbox.
What's wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the toolscript manager tag:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />
```

you can place it above the autocompleteExtender.

Answer (score 1):

I think your web method is not called at all.
Try to call the asmx file from the browser like this:

```
http://localhost/app1/Autocomplete.asmx
```

Change your html code like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtArama" CssClass="search-field"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="TxtArama" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetProducts" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false"                Enabled="True">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

It should call the webmethod after the second char entered in the text box (MinimumPrefixLength="2")

Comment: ok Method is calling  true returned Array  but not list textbox bellow returned array items 
webmethod calling not problem. It's Ok.